# Flink sql exception org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting union

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am creating a flink table on a stream.Stream has date_recorded field in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS] but it was defined as string data type.I want to use this field as event-time attribute .So i defined it as timestamp field in the DDL as below and created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_behaviour (
user_id BIGINT,
order_id BIGINT,
date_recorded TIMESTAMP(3),
proctime AS PROCTIME()   -- generates processing-time attribute using computed column
) WITH (
     'connector' = 'kafka',  -- using kafka connector
     'topic' = 'xxx',  -- kafka topic
     'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',  
     'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'xxx'
     'format' = 'avro-confluent',
     'avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://xxx',
 'avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'user_schema'
)
```

when i run select * on this table it is giving me below exception

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
  org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting union
```

Is there a way to convert string field to a timestamp and use it as eventime attribute?

Comment: You example seems incomplete. It doesn't specify a format. And don't know where the Avro exception should come from.

Comment: Updated the query.I am using avro format.